# Is there any why we can use Shopify metaobjects and able to retrieve data based on the range of values

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I have the following setup in Shopify

Metaobjects:

```
 1. Date Entry
    1.1 Date - String - Display name
    1.2 [Activity Entry] - Array of Activity Entry metaobject IDs
 2. Activity Entry
    2.1 Activity Name
    2.2 Activity Location
    2.3 Activity Description
```

The actual data is a log bigger than this, but the above structure is enough to make my point.
Here my pain point is I want to retrieve all the "Date Entries" based on the given range. Eg. From: 12-Jan-2023 To: 30-Jan-2023
But as per my experience, we can only retrieve the metaobjects by exact match and not by using some operators like greater than or less than etc.
What I am doing is, I loop through the entire date range and make one call for each date. And I am sure there will be a better way of doing the same.

Here are the docs that I have referred to:
https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2023-10/objects/metaobject

Answer (score 0):

It seems `as of now` it's not possible as with metaobjects you can only query 2 fields

- display_name
- updated_at

Ref: https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2023-01/queries/metaobjects

> You may wonder if we can use the `date field` as `display_name` and add a condition based on that but unfortunately, it's also not working.

For now, Your best choice of filtering is either to filter on the client side or develop a third-party API that will fetch all records and filter and send you filtered data.

[image]

if any doubt please comment.